# PostgreSQL COPY command - how to write query in more than one line

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

I'm using the `PostgreSql` database. I want to select some data from database and copy it in a **csv** file. And this works:

```
\COPY (SELECT * from table) TO '/csv_dir/csv_file.csv';
```

My problem is that it works only if the whole command is in one line only. How can I write the COPY command in more than one line? This sql is what I want to put in more rows.

Comment: it seems you are running this query from psql console. use PgAgent client for this

Comment: I like this answer better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404579/use-psqls-copy-for-a-multi-line-query#42405094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an internal command of `psql`, and like other commands starting with a backslash, `\copy` must fit on a single line.

I presume your purpose is to paste a long query with line breaks without having to edit it.

You may use `COPY` instead of `\COPY`, redirect its output to STDOUT, and redirect this `stdout` to a file. Example:

```
$ psql -At -d test <<EOQ >outfile
COPY
 (select 1,2
  union
  select 3,4)
TO STDOUT;
EOQ
```

Result:

```
$ cat outfile
1   2
3   4
```

If you're already in a psql session and this COPY must exist among other commands, it can also be achieved with this sequence:

```
test=> \t
Showing only tuples.
test=> \o outfile
test=> copy
test->  (select 1,2
test(> union
test(> select 3,4)
test-> to stdout;
test=> \o
test=> \t
Tuples only is off.
```

The `\o outfile` starts capturing the output into the file and `\o` without argument ends it.