# Use psql's \copy for a multi-line query

Tags: postgresql, psql

This is a follow-up question from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517692/327026) for "[Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517635/327026)".

I need to write a client-side CSV file using psql's [`\copy` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY). A one liner works:

```
db=> \copy (select 1 AS foo) to 'bar.csv' csv header
COPY 1
```

However, I have long queries that span several lines. I don't need to show the query, as I can't seem to extend this past one line without a parse error:

```
db=> \copy (
\copy: parse error at end of line
db=> \copy ( \\
\copy: parse error at end of line
db=> \copy ("
\copy: parse error at end of line
db=> \copy "(
\copy: parse error at end of line
db=> \copy \\
\copy: parse error at end of line
```

Is it possible to use `\copy` with a query that spans multiple lines? I'm using psql on Windows.

Comment: You probably have to escape the newlines?

Comment: @Falmarri I've put a few common escape attempts in my question, but from the docs "psql's ... backslash escapes do not apply" to `\copy`, which makes things difficult.

Comment: I have posted an answer her: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44043716/24105 which is a roundabout way to get multiple lines.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The working solution I have right now is to [create a temporary view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html), which can be declared over multiple lines, then select from it in the `\copy` command, which fits comfortably on one line.

```
db=> CREATE TEMP VIEW v1 AS
db->   SELECT i
db->   FROM generate_series(1, 2) AS i;
CREATE VIEW
db=> \cd /path/to/a/really/deep/directory/structure/on/client
db=> \copy (SELECT * FROM v1) TO 'out.csv' csv header
COPY 2
db=> DROP VIEW v1;
DROP VIEW
```

Comment: Do you need to explicitly remove the view if it is temp view?

Comment: @nyxz that's correct, you don't need to drop this view. It may only be necessary if you have multiple queries to process with `v1`.

Comment: Easiest solution I have found. Thanks!

Comment: what about if you only have read only permission on the database?

Answer (score 7):

You can combine the server side COPY command with the \g psql command to produce a multi-line query to local file:

```
db=# COPY (
    SELECT department, count(*) AS employees
    FROM emp
    WHERE role = 'dba'
    GROUP BY department
    ORDER BY employees
) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER \g department_dbas.csv
COPY 5
```

I describe this technique in detial here https://hakibenita.com/postgresql-unknown-features#use-copy-with-multi-line-sql

Comment: Elegant! Should supercede other answers, imho.

Comment: You could even skip `COPY` entirely, just use `\g`s formatting-option clauses: `SELECT ... ORDER BY employees \g (format=csv) department_dbas.csv` (header is generated by default here). Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-G and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-PSET-FORMAT

Answer (score 5):

We may use `HEREDOC` to feed multiline SQL to `psql` and use

```
# Putting the SQL using a HEREDOC
tr '\n' ' ' << SQL| \psql mydatabase
\COPY (
  SELECT
    provider_id,
    provider_name,
    ...
) TO './out.tsv' WITH( DELIMITER E'\t', NULL '', )
SQL
```

Source: https://minhajuddin.com/2017/05/18/how-to-pass-a-multi-line-copy-sql-to-psql/